# Automate Tab Colour in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Good afternoon,
I have cells the first has a date and the second has a date, and the third checks the first two. If the first cell has a value it returns "OPEN", if the second cell has a value it instead returns "WAITING",

eg. `Cell F4 "=IF(D4=0,"",IF(AND(D4>0,E4=0),"OPEN","WAITING"))"`

and then I put a date in that cell replacing the formula.

Then another cell checks the whole column and if it contains "OPEN" or "WAITING" it's value is "OPEN", if not it's value is "CLOSED",

eg. `Cell M2 "=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(F2:F1000,{"OPEN","WAITING"})),"OPEN","CLOSED")"`

Then I have VBA on the tab colour, which changes to either green if that cell is "CLOSED" or red if it's "OPEN".

eg.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$M$2" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case "OPEN"
            Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
        Case "CLOSED"
            Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
        Case Else
            Me.Tab.Color = vbOrange
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

This all works except for the tab colour. I have to open the M2 cell (which has calculated correctly) and press enter to activate the tab colour change.

The cells that are checking previous cells are not always column F, some are different. The final value is always M2 in every sheet.

The reason I tried to do this was so I wouldn't need to change the tab colour manually. Is there a better way to do this? I'm currently achieving no automation, if anything it's slightly more work.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event does not trigger on value change of a formula. It only triggers if the static value in that cell is changed either manually by a user edit or by a VBA edit. You could check out the `Worksheet_Calculate` event that triggers everytime something calculates in the worksheet, but that will be run on every formula calculation.

Comment: Thank you,

I have changed that and it is triggering but I get the error "Compile Error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name", I tried changing it and I tried using just one "Workbook_SheetCalculate" on the workbook, instead of a "Worksheet_Calculate" on each sheet, but it's not working for me. Sorry, I google a piece of VBA once every year or so.

Thank you

Adam

Comment: Note that the [Worksheet.Calculate event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)) has no `Target`. Instead it runs on **every** calculation. Make sure to check the official documentation of the event.

Comment: Thank you

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("M2").Value = "OPEN" Then
        Me.Tab.Color = vbRed
    Else
        Me.Tab.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End Sub looks like it is working :)